# Best software to monitor inbound and outbound connections including source and destination info

Tags: network-monitor, internet

I have searched StackExchange, SuperUser, and the internet trying to identify software that will allow me to monitor inbound and outbound connections including source and destination info.

**NOTE: I am not interested in measuring only data usage or volume of inbound or outbound traffic.**

Listed below are four of the most frequently recommended programs, but many of the resources I found were dated.

- TCPView (Sysinternals),
- Wireshark,
- Currports (Nirsoft), and
- CommView (Tamos)

Are there any newer and improved programs for monitoring inbound and outbound connections including source and destination info?

Does any one program stand head-and-shoulders above the others?

Thanks!

gfr92y

Comment: What features are you looking for? What kind of data do you need to monitor?

Comment: Wireshark isn't new, but it gets frequent updates and has a lot more features than the others you mentioned so in that sense it stands head-and-shoulders above the others. Try Wireshark,